# IDE Breakpoints for GWT 2.5 SourceMaps in Chrome?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I have started using GWT 2.5 with Eclipse as my IDE. When using the debugger in Chrome, it is onerous to sort through the source file listing to set my breakpoints. It is even worse when I already have the relevant code open in Eclipse, and I have to find it in Chrome now.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint in Eclipse, and make use of that in Chrome?

This seems like a natural concept given the existence of SourceMaps. If it isn't already a part of the SourceMaps specification, perhaps it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible in Eclipse (yet?)

I've been told JetBrains is working on it for IntelliJ IDEA though.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. Maybe this will surface in Eclipse next year.

Comment: The tools are already here (at least for Chrome), they _just_ have to be wired together (Google Plugin for Eclipse + [Chrome Dev Tools](https://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/))

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Javascript, then why not just add the line

```
debugger;
```

to your code?
It should pause execution on that line, and you can do it from eclipse/whatever IDE you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't "just" do that, though it's another possibility I didn't know of, even if it doesn't precisely target my original question. GWT compiles Java to Javascript, but I can try calling a native method to inject the debugger function. It's still inconvenient relative to the interactivity of a more Java centric debugging style. This also will not work for libraries I am using (and possibly 20 methods deep, and framework event triggered, your pick), and which are also getting compiled to Javascript for me. I'll tell you if it works out for me when I get a chance to try it.